# storig DB results locally/cache for future operations

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I want to access the DB only once and store the results in local memory/cache for future actions.
for Eg: I want to execute this query first;

```
$query = "select * from songs";
```

and store the results locally so that I can use it later to execute queries like this;

```
   $query1 = "select * from songs order by song_id asc";
   $query2 = "select song_name from songs where song_id='5'";
```

I am using PHP to access the DB.

Comment: Compelled to ask "why"?  MySQL has a very high performance for these types of queries (assuming reasonable data size), and also has a built in query cache which can boost performance further.  Unless this is driven by a specific problem, recommend you do not take it further.  If specific problem, post it here for advice.

Comment: Oh..sorry, I didn't know that. where can I learn more about how MySQL does this. Thanks a lot, I learnt something from you today :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas:

1. Use a "local" in-process SQL-database such as [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). SQLite is *very fast* (in many [trivial] cases it performs faster than MySQL, PostgreSQL or Firebird) and supports a good subset of SQL-92 syntax, but there is extra overhead to populate the "data-set" (SQLite DB) and building any indices, etc. This approach allows for great flexibility and allows persistence.
2. Use [memcached](http://memcached.org/) or similar. However, memcached *won't fit the model envisioned*. In the models where memcached does work, an approach like this can work really well.
3. One could "just" store the objects/rows and then perform the query manually over the in-memory array (without the SQL syntax).
4. There may be some *transparent* caching systems such as [the MTCache research project](ftp://ftp.research.microsoft.com/users/palarson/mtcacheicde2004.pdf). I have no experience with these and do not know if there is a viable solution [for PHP].

**All of the above suggestions depend heavily upon exact context/situation and *may actual interfere* with performance and/or 'correct results'.** Remember that MySQL actually performs a good bit of internal work to ensure the data pages/cache are 'hot' and may perform other caching as it sees fit; coupled with good indices I could not actually recommend any of the above except for "offline" operations or cases where a *performance analysis* indicated it was required to meet [*functional requirements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_requirement).

Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable comments...I am learning a lot here daily :)